# Find and print the product of all the entries in array

Tags: java

Okay I have tried to write a simple Java code in BlueJ, that finds and prints the product of all the entries in data such as if data is {1,2,3,4} then the result will be 24.

And my code is below:

```
public class Product {
    public static int[] product(int[] a) {
         int [] s = new int[a.length];
        for (int i =0; i< a.length; i++)
            s[i] = a[i]*a[i];
        return s; //the definition of your method...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //calling the method to seek if compiles
        int[] results = Product.product(new int[] { 1,2,3,4 });
        //printing the results
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(results));
    }
}
```

The above code is giving me the square of each number, which is not what I want to have, somehow I have modify the code that the result will be 24 but I couldn't figure it out, anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: Pointer: Why does the `product` method return an array? From your problem statement, it should return a single `int`.

Comment: @qqilihq, that is true, l wasn't so sure, how to modify it, that's why I posted the rather "wrong" code.

Comment: I assume that you are in the progress of **learning**, so the comment should give you a clear hint on what to change instead of just providing a solution. A second hint: Think, how you as a human would solve such a problem and **after** that take the step to coding. Of course you can just pick up ready working examples from the given answers, but you will do yourself no favor in understanding the fundamentals. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you are first writing Java it is important to know that variable, function and class names are quite important. Please note that having `Product.product()` is not a good idea, since the function name is almost the same as the class name. Anyway, regarding your code. Your code is indeed returning the square of your input, what you would want is the following:

```
public class Product {
    public static int getProduct(int[] input) {
        int total = 1;
        for (int v : input) {
            total *= v;
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

This will return an integer value with the product of your input array. This also uses a for-each loop instead of a regular for-loop for readability. Also you don't need the index in this case. Good luck with it!

Comment: thank you but how should I adjust the rest of the code, in order to check my numbers? I tried like this and it didn't really work:   public class Product {
    public static int getProduct(int[] input) {
        int total = 1;
        for (int v : input) {
            total *= v;
        }
        return total;
    }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        //calling the method to seek if compiles
        int total = Product.getProduct(int{ 1,2,3,4 });
        //printing the results
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(results));
    }
}

Comment: @Acemi the code provided by Alex should work. You forgot to print the variable total. You only need to "System.out.println(total)" in order for the program to work. So change the last line for this one.

Comment: @BoydyBoydy Indeed. I omitted the 'print' function because the question was specific about a function to get a Product from an int array. That's up to the original poster to implement. Likewise for Exception handling, type checking, when appliable..

Comment: @AlexvandenHoogen Thats okay Alex, i was referring to Acemi's comment code that was posted above my question, sorry I forgot that the answerer would receive the comment as well.

Comment: @Alex van den Hoogen as well as BoydyBoydy, okay boys, I have done a screenshot about my current problem, so what would you guys suggest in order to get rid of the error msg so I can compile it?http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o756/deli0102/IT/java_error_product_code_01_may_2014_zps23612424.png

Comment: @Acemi you call for `getproduct(int[])` which doesn't exists, because it is `getProduct(int[])` with a capital P. Programming is case-sensitive, so remember that the next time.

Comment: @Alex van den Hoogen right now i am not at home. once i am at home i will retry it and confirm whether l managed it or not. thx in advance.

Comment: @AlexvandenHoogen , okay I did a correction for the p, still error message, my screenshot: http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o756/deli0102/java_error_msg_02_may_2014_zps08d51eb3.png

Comment: Tour `main` method is outside of your Class. Methods in Java should always be inside of classes. Read the tutorial or book which you are following to get a better understanding of how to code and how to do OO programming.

Comment: @Alex van den Hoogen , I am keep doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

First, your `product` method needs to return an `int` rather than an `int []`.

You need to maintain the product as a variable. You can set it to 1 initially, and then multiply it by each element of the `a` array in turn; then you just return this value.